# ¿Como puedo saber cuando haya terminado de ejecutar un comando cmd desde vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, cmd

Estoy trabajando con ffmpeg y deseo ejecutar los comandos desde un form (vb.net) pero quisiera saber como puedo saber cuando ese proceso haya terminado. Actualmente estoy usando:

```
    Dim Proc As New System.Diagnostics.Process
    Proc.StartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo("C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe")
    Proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -ss 00:00:14.435 -vframes 1 out.png"
    Proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True
    Proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = False
    Proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    Proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
    Proc.Start()
```

¿Como se cuando el proceso haya terminado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes 2 opciones.

1. Si quieres que tu código bloquee hasta que el proceso haya terminado, puedes usar `.WaitForExit()`:

   ```
   ' ...
   Proc.Start()
   Proc.WaitForExit()
   ```
2. Si quieres recibir una notificación de forma asincrónica cuando el proceso termine, puedes registrarte al evento `Exited`. Si haces esto, debes asignar la propiedad `EnableRaisingEvents` a `True` también:

   ```
   ' ...
   Proc.EnableRaisingEvents = True
   AddHandler Proc.Exited, Sub(o, s) Console.WriteLine("El process terminó")
   Proc.Start()
   ```

[Referencia](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.diagnostics.process.exited(v=vs.110).aspx)